# strange loading / not loading viewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

When I use this line of code in the viewDidLoad of the app's main viewController, it is just getting completely ignored:

```
[self presentModalViewController:nextController  animated:YES];
```

The nextControler doesn't load, nothing at all happens.
I do know the code is being "executed" since I put an NSLog before and after it and also ran through the program with a breakpoint.

When I call this line elsewhere in the code, it works perfectly as expected, but in viewDidLoad it is being ignored.

So I tried this code to see if there would be any difference:

```
[self.view addSubview:nextController.view];
```

This is loading the nextController view over top of my main view but some of it is transparent so that the main view shows through, and when I try to click on a button in the nextController, it is actually NSLog'ing as a press on a button in the main view below it.

Does anybody have any idea what might be happening here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put this line of code in `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called before the view controller is inserted into the view controller hierarchy. That's why it just doesn't know how to present a modal view controller at this point. Try moving the code into `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Wow - THANK YOU!   I have never used viewDidAppear before and have never had a problem but this worked like a charm. Thanks again!